# Javascript: Assign if undefined operator not working

Tags: javascript, undefined, default-value

Here is an example where I use the `||` operator to assign a default value if the argument is `undefined`.

```
output = function (data) {
    console.log("data.flag =", data.flag);
}

main = function (flag) {
    output({
        flag: flag || true;
    });
}

main(true);  // data.flag = true 
main(false); // data.flag = true
```

However, the operation is ignored so always that the default value is assigned. How can I fix this? Here on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch4jW/) - you have to open the console to see the output.

Comment: `flag || true` will always be equal to `true` if `flag` is boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is ***not*** an 'assign if undefined operator', although its semantics allow it to be used in a way that makes it *seem* like that's what it does. It's the *OR* operator. It evaluates the right side if and only if the left side is 'falsey'—that is, when converted to a Boolean value, it is `false`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `||` returns `true` if either operand is `true`; if both are `false`, returns `false`.

Try using a more explicit test:

```
output({
    flag: (typeof flag === "undefined") ? true : flag;
});
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a wrapper function for `(typeof flag === "undefined") ? true : flag;` in a common library such as [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass in false you have this

```
flag: false || true;
```

And if you know how `||` works, if the left side is falsey, it will take the right hand side.

You need to check for undefined since false is FALSE

```
flag: flag!==undefined ? flag : true;
```

Other option would be check argument length

```
flag: arguments.length ? flag : true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
flag: typeof flag === 'undefined' ? true : !!flag;
```

`||` is not good for what you want to use it. It will return the result of the first operand if it is truthy, and return the second otherwise. For example `false || true` returns `true`.

My example will return `true` if `flag` is `undefined`, and will return `flag` casted to boolean (so either `true` or `false`) otherwise - so you end up with a clean flag, no tricks :).

*One more tip: don't use tricks that you do not understand :). They will lead to strange bugs.*

Answer (score 0):

You should check type

```
main = function (flag) {
    output({
        flag: (flag===undefined)?true:flag;
    });
}
```